# How do I make a regex part optional and finish regex at the same point if that optional part contains a string end ($)?

Tags: java, regex

```
String s1 = "NetworkElement=Test,testWork=1:[456]";
String s2 = "NetworkElement=Test,testWork=1";
String regex = "(.*):\\[(.*)\\]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(s2);
if (matcher2.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher2.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher2.group(2));
}

/*
Expected output:
for s1 : NetworkElement=Test,testWork=1
         456
for s2 : NetworkElement=Test,testWork=1
         0
*/
```

Problem : This regex is working fine for String s1 but not for s2. for string s2, matcher2.find() return false.

Comment: See [ask]. describe your problem before showing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*?)(?::\[(.*?)])?$
^(.*?)(?::\[([^\]\[]*)])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OcJfYe/1).

In Java:

```java
String regex = "^(.*?)(?::\\[(.*?)])?$";
// Or
String regex = "^(.*?)(?::\\[([^\\]\\[]*)])?$";
```

I added the `^` and `$` anchors since you are using `matcher.find()`. If you switch to `matcher.matches()`, you can remove the anchors.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)`  - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?::\[(.*?)])?` - an optional sequence of `:[`, then Group 2 capturing any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible and then a `]` char (if you use `[^\]\[]*` it will match zero or more chars other than square brackets)
- `$` - end of string.